# var labels = this.Controls.OfType<Label>(); Control all labels except 1

Tags: c#, label, var

I have a maze game that uses labels as walls and .IntersectsWith to handle colision. My problem is that since my "player" is also a label it messes things up with my code.
What i want is for the player to be able to move meanwhile it also cant colide with all the other labels.

What the problem really is is that this part makes the player unable to move for some reason. Never mind the if () with  break it was just an experiment.

```
 var labels = this.Controls.OfType<Label>();

        foreach (var label in labels)
        {
            if (label.Bounds.IntersectsWith(player.Bounds))
            {
                break;
            }
            if (player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(label.Bounds))
            {

 namespace mazeGame
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool down;
    bool left;
    bool right;
    bool up;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            right = true;
            left = false;
            up = false;
            down = false;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            left = true;
            right = false;
            up = false;
            down = false;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            up = true;
            left = false;
            right = false;
            down = false;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            down = true;
            left = false;
            up = false;
            right = false;
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        var labels = this.Controls.OfType<Label>();

        foreach (var label in labels)
        {
            if (label.Bounds.IntersectsWith(player.Bounds))
            {
                break;
            }
            if (player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(label.Bounds))
            {

                if (right == true)
                {
                    right = false;
                    left = true;
                }
                else if (left == true)
                {
                    left = false;
                    right = true;
                }
                else if (up == true)
                {
                    up = false;
                    down = true;
                }
                else if (down == true)
                {
                    down = false;
                    up = true;
                }
            }



            if (right == true)
            {
                player.Left += 1;
            }
            if (left == true)
            {
                player.Left -= 1;
            }
            if (up == true)
            {
                player.Top -= 1;
            }
            if (down == true)
            {
                player.Top += 1;
            }


        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void panel2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should be storing the state of your game in some entirely non-UI mechanism.  Then display that current state using some UI specific technology.  When you want to make changes, make it to the underlying state, and then simply update the UI based on the changes to the underlying state.

Comment: I did not understand one part of that. I am a complete noob to programing in general and especially c#. And im not a native english speaker.

Comment: You can add .Except(new[] { player })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude your `player` label from your selection in this manner:

```
var labels = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(l => l.Name != "Player")
```

Comment: This should solve your problem, tho, as Servy says in the comments, perhaps rethinking your structure is in order.  Please be sure to mark answers on your previous question.  Let me know how this works for you and if there is more I can do.

Comment: Didnt work. It doesnt let me put in 1.Name and just gives me 100 errors. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Ok, `Name` might not be the right property.  How about if you put a value like "player" into the `Tag` property of the player label.  Then do `l => l.Tag != "player"` @user3480405

Comment: It didnt like that either.

Comment: @user3480405 Oh, make sure you have `using System.Linq` at the top of your file.  That'll get rid of many of those errors.

Comment: I already have that in the top. Sorry i will not remove that part later.

Comment: Ok, What is your E-mail?

Comment: sent now. Named mazegame.rar

Comment: great, i'll take a look at it in a later tonight. (i'm MST)

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help via E-mail. Solved the problem.